# Why wordpress images only work with only one domain

Tags: dns, wordpress, content-management-system, wpml

I have created many WordPress sites and there is something I was never able to fix.

When you have two domains for the same website (such as www.example.com and www.example.fr) only one shows correctly and the alternative doesn't show it's images.

I guess this is a common problem that might happen to a lot of you. Any idea to help me fix it ?

Comment: Can you send use a link the website that you are referring to in www.example.fr so we can see?

Comment: sure, check draidel.com and draidel.com.ar

Comment: But draidel.com redirects to  draidel.com.ar?

Comment: it redirects to .com.ar if your browser is in spanish (at least, that is how it should work)

Comment: Ok, last question before I answer. The problem is with draidel.com.ar, and not draidel.com?

Comment: thats right. draidel.com shows correctly but some images and icons don't with .com.ar

Answer (score 0):

First, check that both WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are set properly in

**wp-admin/ >> Settings >> General**

If that is not the case, see the error messages in the console:

> (index):1 Font from origin 'http://draidel.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://draidel.com.ar' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

You can resolve this by adding the following to you .htaccess

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "draidel.com"
```

You may need to change the permissions of .htaccess as WordPress loves to change it randomly.

Comment: both WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are both set to "http://draidel.com", if I switch it for .com.ar then its .com the one that doesn't show properly and I added that line to my .htaccess file but I still see the same problem :(

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong domain. Change that in `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "draidel.com"`... also make sure to clear your cache or view the site in incognito.

Comment: it seems it only works with  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"  which is not very clean.. but doest the trick